# Cordova - share the common code

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

Is there is any way to have a common project which contains plugin, java script file etc and there is a multiple Cordova project which can access/get those plugins and java script files.

For an example, **Cordova-Project-A** and **Cordova-Project-B** has some common plugins, CSS files and java script files. So need to separate these common codes and place it on separate project.

Note: Cordova templates will do this work. But if there is any plugin/JS file update in the template, it won't reflect anything on Cordova projects.

Comment: use **[npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)**?

Comment: This isn't anything related to programming per se. You might get close votes...

Comment: @deostroll, seems pretty related to me.

Answer (score 0):

there is. this place is called [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), and it serves as a giant, worldwide, warehouse for javascript developers. by the way, cordova is already using it to power its plugin system.

to join the party:

- create the desired projects to contain the common, extracted, code as npm projects (i.e. use [`npm init`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) on them).
- use npm's [`link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to always have the updated source in all consuming projects.

Comment: Can you please let me know how we will maintain this structure in git repository. Because after doing npm link again we have same set of code which doesn't want to be in git.

Comment: i'm not sure i follow, if you have another question, please phrase it specifically as you can, and post it in another question.